# Validation errors when linking authentication with Dialogflow / Google Action

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

We are trying to get DialogFlow / Google Actions to link to an external OAuth account within a conversation. Upon following the examples we are consistently getting request validation errors that we don't know how to resolve. As far as I can tell we are doing everything by the book.

Our questions:

1. Why won't DialogFlow kick off the authentication process?
2. The documented [webhook response for requesting the sign-in helper](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking#request_the_signin_helper) not have the same schema as a standard [DialogFlow webhook response](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/v1/dialogflow-webhook#response). Is the sign-in helper response supposed to be used for something else?...

Things we have tried:

- We have configured our app and OAuth credentials per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking#step_2_enable_account_linking)
- We have verified that we can fetch an OAuth token from the service via the OAuth 2.0 playground
- We have enabled transactions on the Action.

Our intent code is as follows:

```
const { DialogflowApp } = require('actions-on-google'); 
const { ActionsSdkApp } = require('actions-on-google');

function processV2Request (request, response) {
  ...
  let app = new DialogflowApp({request: request, response: response});
  let sdkapp = new ActionsSdkApp({request: request, response: response});
  const actionHandlers = {
    'pto': () => {
        app.askForSignIn();
    }
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

When we execute this intent, we receive the following debug error message about a `speech` field.

```
"agentToAssistantJson": {
  "message": "Unexpected apiai response format: Empty speech response",
  "apiResponse": {
    "id": "751e4716-a94d-4d11-908d-3ee193092d9c",
    "timestamp": "2017-12-05T19:52:01.962Z",
    "lang": "en-us",
    "result": {},
    "status": {
      "code": 206,
      "errorType": "partial_content",
      "errorDetails": "Webhook call failed. Error: Failed to parse webhook JSON response: Cannot find field: speech in message google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.WebhookResponse."
    }
  }
}
```

If instead we try using the ActionsSdkApp, `sdkapp.askForSignIn()`, we get an error message about a `conversation_token` field.

```
"agentToAssistantJson": {
  "message": "Unexpected apiai response format: Empty speech response",
  "apiResponse": {
    "id": "7de79093-6db8-44ee-8717-16b0f317174c",
    "timestamp": "2017-12-05T19:54:29.709Z",
    "lang": "en-us",
    "result": {},
    "status": {
      "code": 206,
      "errorType": "partial_content",
      "errorDetails": "Webhook call failed. Error: Failed to parse webhook JSON response: Cannot find field: conversation_token in message google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.WebhookResponse."
    },
  }
}
```

And if it's helpful, here's our package.json. It's the DialogFlow default as of recently, with a bumped up version of `actions-on-google`.

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "~6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^1.6.x",
    "firebase-admin": "^4.2.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.5.7",
    "apiai": "^4.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you intentionally using the Dialogflow v2 API? (which is different than the Actions-on-Google v2 API.)

Comment: We've tried it with both the v1 and v2 APIs and get problems either way. Is v1 the recommended version?

Comment: Dialogflow v2 is still in beta and not recommended for production yet. Mostly wanted to narrow things down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We determined that in addition to having Transactions enabled for the app, you must also change the `Development Sandbox` toggled to `Active`:

[image]